# stl vector reserve

Tags: c++, vector, allocation

I was trying to pre-allocate a vector of integer like this

```
vector<int> tmp_color; tmp_color.reserve(node_obj[node].c_max);
    for(int tmp_color_idx = 0; tmp_color_idx < node_obj[node].c_max; tmp_color_idx++)
         tmp_color[tmp_color_idx] = tmp_color_idx;
```

where node_obj[node].c_max is > 0 (I checked). size of tmp_color appears to be zero anyways, after the for loop. If there something wrong with the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make assignments in the loop as you wrote I suggest the following way:

```
vector<int> tmp_color(node_obj[node].c_max);
for(int tmp_color_idx = 0; tmp_color_idx < node_obj[node].c_max; tmp_color_idx++)
     tmp_color[tmp_color_idx] = tmp_color_idx;
```

Answer (score 3):

`reserve` does not actually add elements to a `vector`; that's what `resize` does.  `reserve` just reserves space for them.  You either need to add the elements one-by-one in your loop, using:

```
tmp_color.push_back(tmp_color_idx);
```

or change your use of `reserve` to `resize`.

Comment: In other words, `reserve()` changes the **capacity** of the vector, while `resize()` changes the **size** of the vector. The **size** indicates how many *initialized* elements are actually present in the vector, and the **capacity** indicates the maximum number of elements it can hold before it needs to reallocate when new elements are added. The size is always less than or equal to the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You are rather lucky that it didn't crash.

```
tmp_color[tmp_color_idx] = tmp_color_idx;
```

In the above line, you are accessing out of bounds of the vector.

reserve() doesn't increase the size of the vector, resize() should be used.
To me, the method used by Elalfer is even better to pre-allocate the size.

Comment: @In silico: If you look at Visual studio impl, overloaded subscript operator checks against size(), not against max_size(). reserve() call just updates max_size(), but not size(). So it crashes when operator[] gets invoked.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading Elalfer's answer and not the OP's question.